# How I can update a sqlite Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I want to make an update to my sqlite database of my android application, but I get an error in the update method.

my code:

```
public void addInfo(View view){

        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtContacto);

        String TAG = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).getText().toString(); 
        String FACH = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();

        ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();
        werte.put("info",et.getText().toString());

        mDatenbank.update(TAG, werte, "name="+FACH, null);

        Toast.makeText(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.db_info_add),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


    }
```

TAG is my Tablename
FACH is a column

Table layout:

id (int) | name(text) | info(text)

Comment: please show logcat and your database.java class

Comment: "i get an error" means absolutely nothing unless you tell us **what the error is**. We can't read your mind or see your screen from where we are, and we can't see the logcat either. If you give us no info, we can't help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would work if FACH contained a quotes needed for string literal, as in `String FACH="'I am quoted'"`. It would still be wrong: the real solution is using `whereArgs`, something like this:

```
mDatenbank.update(TAG,werte,"name=?",new String[] { FACH });
```

(Disclaimer: I don't use Java, my code may be ridiculously wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a great example: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

```
updateContact()
    // Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

The best would be to show us the logcat